# How to put the values from database to a specific column in the table

Tags: php, html, arrays, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Here is the code for the **fetching of the data from the database**

```
<?php

    $uid  = $_SESSION['UID'];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT user.*,score.* from `user` join score ON user.USERID=score.USERID WHERE user.USERID=$uid ");

    if (!$result) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
        exit();
    }
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['SCORE']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['AVERAGE']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['POINTS']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".'0'."</td>";
        echo "<td>".'0'."</td>";
        echo "<td>".'0'."</td>";
        echo "<td>".'0'."</td>";
        echo "<td>".'0'."</td>";
        echo "<td>".'0'."</td>";
        echo "<td>".'0'."</td>";
        echo "<td>".'0'."</td>";
        echo "<td>".'0'."</td>";
        echo "<td>".'0'."</td>";
        echo "<td>".'0'."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
?>
```

Here is the database where i want for **each actcode** it will go to a **certain row of the table** of the output

[image]

Here is the **current output** where im getting **all of the data from the database in the Lesson Exam Row**. 
[image]

**This should be the desired output.**  if the value of the ACTCODE of the user in the database is 1 then it should be in output of the lesson exam row, 2 if in module 1 row and 3 if in module 2 row and so on
[image]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The desired output, is all values on the same row with different columns or different rows and columns?

Comment: if the value of the ACTCODE of the user in the database is 1 then it should be in output of the lesson exam row, 2 if in module 1 row and 3 if in module 2 row and so on

Comment: The title should be How to put the values from database to a specific **column** in the table, correct?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, you want to print n times 0 then the data and then m times 0 again. where n + 3 + m is the number of columns on your table.

Based on your comments I changed my whole answer, now the strategy is to place the rows on a array and echo the array after it is organized.

```
// this function will echo the data
function dataBlock($row)
{
    return "<td>".$row['SCORE']."</td>".
            "<td>".$row['AVERAGE']."</td>".
            "<td>".$row['POINTS']."</td>";
}

// the beginning of your code...

$numModules = 4; // a var to store the number of modules
$rows = []
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    array_push($rows[$row['USERID']][$row['ACTCODE']], dataBlock($row));
}

foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($k = 0 ; $k < $numModules; $k++) { echo $row[$k]; }
    echo '</tr>'
}
```

Comment: It fix the problem but it add additional empty column in the table. check the image above.

Comment: I added a var to fix the number of prints of the final part and you might need to add additional echos for the last columns as they are not in the same pattern as the others

Comment: Do you want all on the same line?

Comment: Yes sir i want it on the same line just like the first line. @Pedro Henrique

Comment: `.push()`? Its not javascript

Comment: There are errors in the code like Notice: Undefined offset: 32 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function push() Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C $rows[$row['USERID']][$row['ACTCODE']].push(dataBlock($row)); @PedroHenrique

Comment: True, I got confused with the languages, changed `.push()` to `array_push()` now

Comment: there is an error shows: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in,    In the code, array_push($rows[$row['USERID']][$row['ACTCODE']], dataBlock($row)); @PedroHenrique